# Grails Gradle dependencies same library different versions

Tags: grails, gradle

I am stuck using gradle in Grails. There are different libraries that I have that depend on the same library but with different versions.

So, let say:

library A: depends on library Z version 1.0

library B: depends on library Z version 2.0

What I have so far is:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.something.something:libraryA:some_version"
    compile "org.something.something:libraryZ:1.0"

    compile "org.something.something:libraryB:some_version"
    compile "org.something.something:libraryZ:2.0"
}
```

**How can I accomplish this in gradle?** Thank you!

Note: I searched and tried some suggestions on the internet but none of them worked.

Comment: Gradle will use the 2.0 of libraryZ

Comment: But 2.0 of libraryZ is incompatible with libraryA

Comment: Then you can't do it.   You can only have one version of a library be accessible when running.  If you try and have 2 versions on the classpath, you almost always end up with vague class identifiers.  i.e. a class a.b.c.classD will exist in both libraries, so when you import it, the classLoader can't tell which one to load, and it errors out.

Comment: If library A truly can't work with v2.0 of Z, and library B truly can't work with v1.0 of Z, then you can't use both library A and B together.

Comment: Any other workaround that I can do? libraryZ is not backward compatible and not even forward compatible; so I am pretty much stuck.

Comment: this wouldn not work anywhere not only in grails

Comment: I could imagine to resolve the conflict by keeping both versions of `libraryZ` but each version must only be used within `libraryA` and `libraryB`.
Is this possible in Gradle?